# Handle large dataset in birt

Tags: birt

I am running into issues with out of memory exceptions . I need to display a large set of data in a cross tab.  I need to display 5,277,888 rows aggregated into 403,920 rows. I don't think birt can handle this and would like some advice.

These are the options I was thinking

1. Some how fetch some data at a time and aggregate it (might still run out of memory)
2. Find a different reporting framework that renders html
3. Not use cross tab and do all of the aggregation server side and try to display it in a sudo cross tab.

Comment: Are you using a relational database as the back end? (If so, 3 would be my recommendation.)

Comment: Yes, do I could use Hibernate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fetaching large amonunt of data and providing it to BIRT increases data trafic and also many a times (as in your case) lead to system / report engine hang.

What you are thinkning is correct. (Option 3) It is preferable to use aggregate functions in your db and give an already summarized data to BIRT at times.

SQL provides options for cross tab outputs (SQL Pivot Function) as well in case required.